# Myeclipse Project is not deploying after Update Strut Library 2.0 To 2.3

Tags: java, jboss, myeclipse

**After Update My Existing Strut 2.0 Jar With Strut 2.3 ... Project is not deploying on jboss.. Following errror is populating**

Deployment failure on JBoss  4.x. Could not copy all resources to /home/stpl/Software/jboss-4.2.2.GA_new/server/default/deploy/LMSLinuxNew.war. If a file is locked, you can wait until the lock times out to redeploy, or stop the server and redeploy, or manually remove the deployment at /home/stpl/Software/jboss-4.2.2.GA_new/server/default/deploy/LMSLinuxNew.war

=> Done My Side(Stop server... clean Build etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server and manually remove the war from the deploy folder.
Also remove the folder named after the .war file.
Suggest you to remove the temp folder and work folder also.